# Hide Div Scrollbar which has iframe inside it

Tags: css

I have an Iframe inside a div.

```
 <div id="myDiv" style="height: 400px; width: 400px; border-color: red; border-style: solid;">

    <iframe src="http://www.ibm.com" id="myIframe" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto;"></iframe>

</div>
```

I was able to hide the scollbar of iFrame.

I also want to hide the scroll bar of div.
How can i achieve that.

Comment: Make a fiddle demo and reduce problem.

Comment: Do you want to prevent user from scrolling or just to hide the srcollbar? In both situations this is a dublicate. Just tell us to which question should we refer to when flagging.

Comment: i don't want to prevent users from scrolling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide scroll bar, but still being able to scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Comment: I tried with the solution provided in the link. I have created a fiddle. It still shows the scorllbar. I want users to scroll without scroll bar appearing. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yxLj4pqn/

Answer (score 0):

Try to prevent the scroll of the body.

```
head,
body {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way i can solve this my adding some css to div rather than body, i have created a fiddle for this at http://jsfiddle.net/yxLj4pqn/

Comment: Fiddle will not be enough as the whole body is been covered by that iframe. If you have some other source then it will be helpful.